# Methods for storing data in java

Tags: java, csv

In my software I want to store some data, that later they will be used. Something like a database to hold data:

```
Date, source path, destination path, and an array of file names.
```

Also another table to hold information about ftp connection:

```
Host, port, username and password
```

I need to know what methods are available to store and parse these data. I noticed there is a file type called .csv, is this an option for me? And is there any other option?

Comment: `.cvs` files are excel document not related to java. If really you want to store data using "table" concept then you should simply use SQL.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard actually no, cvs is nothing more than a data format for storing comma delimited values. it just so happens to be that Excel can use it.

Comment: @James_Parsons That's right. Actually to make it simple I gave excel as an example, but your comments complete what I wanted to specify (it's just a data format). However, that doesn't change the last part of my comments. Thanks for the added details tho.

Comment: @James_Parsons That's what made me confuse. I thought .cvs is something different than Excel. However I like to know what is the usual and common way for storing the describe info in a program

Comment: @Dan If really you need to store data using "table" concept, follow the path of SQL, else this will be horrible to maintain at end. In the case where you would be scared of learning SQL, you might want to know that the basis can be learned in a couple of hours, even minutes if you are only limited to the example you give us.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Thank you for your help. Yes it seems SQL is the best option. I would choose your respond as the right answer if you post it.

Comment: @Dan You're welcome. No need to post this as an answer just so you accept it. The goal here is knowledge sharing, and (no offence) but I highly doubt this question's answer would help anyone else as there is plenty of information on this. Good luck with learning the basis of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends a lot on how much data you want to store and how you need to access it.

If your application is going to be collecting a lot of structured data, such as user profiles, or product information, ie, if your application is all about a database then, yes as others have commented some sort of SQL database would make sense.

If your needs are more along the lines of just storing some "session" information,  maybe like the last state of a GUI form for example, you might want to just serialize the data and write it to a simple text file.

One simple way to do that would be to serialize the data in a human readable format such as JSON and then write the text to a file, and then read it back and deserialize it when you need to restore it from storage.

If this is what you are looking for take a look at [gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) (from  google), it   provides a very easy what to convert a java object to JSON and back again.

JSON, is just text, so you can just read and write it to a simple text file.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. I had a try with GSON and it seems quite easy to save data in a file and parse them. Just there is something I am not sure about yet. Since obviously the software will be distributed in the future. Is it possible to save the .json file in one of the project folders? I mean does GSON give this option? Thanks

Comment: GSON just does the conversion of object to json (human readable text format) and back.  You are free to store the json any were you like.