# Is it possible to save database file in a project folder of Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database

This post is the continue of my previous question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573557/methods-for-storing-data-in-java/29573867#29573867). So I had a look into how mySQL works with Java, but I noticed that the computer must have a database server to connect to the application. So what will happen when my software is ready and users want to run in a different computers? Can't I save the database file in the directory of the software, so any copy of the program will be connected to its independent database to save and parse data from it?

Just to make it clear, in a part of my software, I needs to keep record of previous interactions. Like a history table.

Would using JSON a better option in this case?

Comment: Cann't you use the Java's default database, `Derby` which is provided by default since `JDK1.6` I guess. Check the directory where `java` is installed, if you find a folder named `db` in there, then you have it :-) Normal queries have the same format in that too.

Comment: Have a look at this [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3d0l5oq3qhrx1xx/dbconnect.zip?dl=0), of mine. If you using Windows, and `JAVA_HOME` variable is set ( as path in Environment Variables ), then simply click on `build.bat` file, this will make it execute. Else write `javac -classpath build -d build view\*.java model\*.java controller\*.java` to compile and `java -classpath .;%JAVA_HOME%\db\lib\derby.jar connect.database.view.TableView` this to execute. Replace `%JAVA_HOME%` with the path, where this folder resides `jdk1.x.xx` (which contains db folder )

Comment: How many simultaneous updates/inserts? SQLite is a good choice if not too many.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan will I able to include SQLite in the jar file? So when the software get distributed, there will be one database for each jar file. So user enter and remove data for itself. Can SQLite do this?

Comment: @Dan a jar file is just a zip file, so yes, you can include it. Many android / iphone apps use SQLite as their local database, and you can do the same thing on desktop. It's a file-based database, so you just need to reference its file path to use it.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Thanks for your comment. Indeed SQLite is what I was looking for. I just tried it and it really works as a local DB. I would choose your comment as the right answer if you post it. btw, in your first comment you mentioned about the number of inserts. Can you explain what you mean please? The software will insert row one at the time and basically it wont be used as a heavy database. So would it be suitable?

Answer (score 2):

In a real world generally database servers are installed on a machine and softwares are installed on different machine.
We let software know the database configuration like database URL /database Name /username/Passwords etc (through property file or through JNDI configurationS).Then java program can connect to database with the help of JDBC driver.

Note:- one Database Server can Host many databases.

If you want to distribute your software without having dependency on client database. Then I would recommend you to use some inmemory DB.This DB you can embed with your software.(alternatively you can write logic that if client database can't be found then use inMemory DB..something like this).

H2 db is my favorite one and it also supports persistent mode and it support s many DB dialects including MYSQL .